# C++ boost library deSerialize object passed over TCP server

Tags: c++, boost

I am receiving an object `class Command` over a TCP server and trying to deserialize it using boost library (The serialization function is included in the code too) using this code:

```cpp
T deSerialize(std::string s) {    //deSerialize
    T t = T();
    std::ifstream ifs(s);
    std::cout << "check \n";

    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);   //<==== Not working
    std::cout << "check2 \n";

    ia >> t;
    return t;
}
```

```cpp
template <class T>
std::string serialize(T obj) {    //Serialize
    std::ofstream ofs("output");
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << obj;
    }
    return "output";
}
```

```cpp
...
while (true) {    //recive data from TCP
        std::fstream dataFile("commands.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::app);

        recv(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);

        dataFile << buf;

        dataFile.close();

        c = deSerialize<Command>("commands.txt"); // <=== This line makes it break :(


    }
...
```

Can someone maybe find the problem?

Comment: What is the _exact_ error message/error you are getting? "<=== not working" is not enough to help you.     And what is the content of "commands.txt" when you call "deSerialize"?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  What is `buf` (and hence the value of `sizeof(buf)`)?  You never check the value returned by `recv`.  Also note that `TCP` data is simply a byte stream -- there's no guarantee that a write of N bytes at one end will result in a read of N bytes at the other.

Comment: also 'this line makes it break' what does that mean, wont compile, crashes, does the wrong thing?

Answer (score 0):

Again [we can't tell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71269684/deserialize-an-object-using-c-boost-library#:%7E:text=I%20can%27t%20really%20tell.%20Perhaps%20because%20your%20example%20is%20not%20selfcontained). It really seems you just don't know how to read stuff from the wire. So I'll show you, starting from [the same example I made for you last time around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71272466/85371).

Also, no need to write to a file first. Just serialize/deserialize directly from streams:

```
template <class T> void my_save(std::ostream& os, T const& obj) {
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(os);
    oa << obj;
}

template <class T> T my_load(std::istream& is) {
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(is);

    T result;
    ia >> result;
    return result;
}
```

If you insist, you can still have the overloads that take a filename, and delegate to the newer, more general interface:

```
template <class T> void my_save(std::string const& filename, T const& obj) {
    std::ofstream ofs(filename, std::ios::binary);
    return my_save<T>(ofs, obj);
}

template <class T> T my_load(std::string const& filename) {
    std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary);
    return my_load<T>(ifs);
}
```

### Connection Sockets

I'm going to show how to use synchronous Boost Asio here, and without any protocol, in the simplest way imaginable.

#### Client

Let's create a client that connects to localhost:8989 and reads a vector of `Command` objects:

```
static constexpr uint16_t port = 8989;

void run_client() {
    tcp::iostream conn(tcp::endpoint{{}, port});

    for (auto&& cmd : my_load<Commands>(conn))
        std::cout << "-----\n" << cmd;
}
```

That's all.

#### Server

To test things, let's also create a server that accepts a single TCP connection and writes a demo vector of `Commands` to it.

```
void run_server() {
    net::io_context ioc;
    tcp::acceptor acc(ioc, {{}, port});
    tcp::iostream conn(acc.accept());

    my_save(conn,
            Commands{
                {'s', 10, 20, "Save"},
                {'q', 21, 31, "Quit"},
                {'l', 32, 42, "Load"},
                {'x', 43, 53, "Exit"},
            });
}
```

Again, that's all.

### Putting It Together

```
int main() {
    std::thread s(run_server);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms); // server must be ready

    run_client();

    s.join();
}
```

The program runs the server in the background, and then runs the client against it, printing like before:

```
-----
letter: s
x     : 10
y     : 20
button: Save
-----
letter: q
x     : 21
y     : 31
button: Quit
-----
letter: l
x     : 32
y     : 42
button: Load
-----
letter: x
x     : 43
y     : 53
button: Exit
```

### [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88135b996f22d5b0)

Listing for future reference:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

namespace net = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using net::ip::tcp;

class Command {
  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive& arch, unsigned) {
        arch& letter& x& y& button;
    }

    char        letter;
    int         x;
    int         y;
    std::string button;

  public:
    Command(char _letter = '\0', int _x = 0, int _y = 0,
            std::string_view _button = {})
        : letter(_letter)
        , x(_x)
        , y(_y)
        , button(_button)
    { }

    char        getLetter() const { return letter; }
    int         getX()      const { return x;      }
    int         getY()      const { return y;      }
    std::string getButton() const { return button; }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Command const& cmd){
        return os << "letter: " << cmd.letter << "\n" //
                  << "x     : " << cmd.x << "\n"      //
                  << "y     : " << cmd.y << "\n"      //
                  << "button: " << cmd.button << "\n";
    }
};
using Commands = std::vector<Command>;

template <class T> void my_save(std::ostream& os, T const& obj) {
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(os);
    oa << obj;
}

template <class T> T my_load(std::istream& is) {
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(is);

    T result;
    ia >> result;
    return result;
}

static constexpr uint16_t port = 8989;

void run_client() {
    tcp::iostream conn(tcp::endpoint{{}, port});

    for (auto&& cmd : my_load<Commands>(conn))
        std::cout << "-----\n" << cmd;
}

void run_server() {
    net::io_context ioc;
    tcp::acceptor acc(ioc, {{}, port});
    acc.listen();

    tcp::iostream conn(acc.accept());

    my_save(conn,
            Commands{
                {'s', 10, 20, "Save"},
                {'q', 21, 31, "Quit"},
                {'l', 32, 42, "Load"},
                {'x', 43, 53, "Exit"},
            });
}

int main() {
    std::thread s(run_server);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms); // server must be ready

    run_client();

    s.join();
}
```